# How to get the id of the previous element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the html:

```
<li> 
    <a href="/someurl" id="4">some text</a>
    <i class="geta glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" onclick="deleteAnch();"></i>   
</li>

<li> 
  <a href="/otherurl" id="5">other text</a>
  <i class="geta glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" onclick="deleteAnch();"></i>

</li>
```

And the jquery:

```
function deleteAnch () {
    var the_id = $(this).prev('a').attr('id');
    //also tried var the_id = $(this).closest('a').attr(id);
    console.log('The id is:', the_id);        
}
```

But in console I get

> The id is: undefined

What is it wrong here and how to fix this?

p.s. I know some similar question is being asked but I still can not get it working using other answers hence the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass current element content i.e. `this` to `deleteAnch` inline click handler.

```
<i class="geta glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" onclick="deleteAnch(this);"></i>
```

Modify function as

```
function deleteAnch (elem) {
    var the_id = $(elem).prev('a').attr('id');
    console.log('The id is:', the_id);        
}
```

---

However as you are using jQuery, you should bind event using it. Pass the function reference of `deleteAnch` and get rid of inline click handler

```
function deleteAnch () {
    var the_id = $(this).prev('a').attr('id');
    console.log('The id is:', the_id);        
}

$('i.glyphicon-remove-circle').on('click', deleteAnch);
```

```js
function deleteAnch() {
  var the_id = $(this).prev('a').attr('id');
  console.log('The id is:', the_id);
}

$('i.glyphicon-remove-circle').on('click', deleteAnch);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/someurl" id="4">some text</a>
    <i class="geta glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle">icon</i> 
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="/otherurl" id="5">other text</a>
    <i class="geta glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle">icon</i>
  </li>
</ul>
```